# estimate for function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, open and let $\Phi:U\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be differentiable with $D\Phi(a)\in Aut(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $a\in U$. I have already proven existence of a constant $C>0$ such that $||D\Phi(a)v||\geq C||v||$ for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Now, I have to proof that there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $\overline{B}(a,\delta)\subset U $ and
$$||\Phi(x)-\Phi(a)||\geq \frac{2}{3} C||x-a||$$
for all $x\in\overline{B}(a,\delta)$

How do I have to go on? I know that since $\Phi$ is differentiable, we can write 
$$\Phi(x)-\Phi(a)=D\Phi(a)(x-a)+R(x-a)$$ with $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{R(x-a)}{||x-a||}=0$$
Can anyone please tell me how to proof this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{R(x-a)}{||x-a||} = 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $|x-a| \leq \delta$ we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{||R(x-a)||}{||x-a||} \leq \frac{C}{3}
\end{equation}

By the triangle inequality,
\begin{equation*}
||\Phi(x)-\Phi(a)|| = ||D\Phi(a)(x-a) + R(x-a)||\geq ||D\Phi(a)(x-a)|| - ||R(x-a)|| \geq C||x-a|| - \frac{C}{3}||x-a|| = \frac{2C}{3}||x-a||. 
\end{equation*}
for all $x \in \overline{B(a;\delta)}$.